# Adobe Illustrator shaper tool artifact

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I realize there is a much easier way to make an octagon in Adobe Illustrator but this is a simplified example to explain the issue I run into and I'm sure there's a simple fix.

If I make a square and copy/paste it - turn the 2nd square 45° and then use the shaper tool to cut all the corners away to make an octagon, each intersection has a little white space. How can I fix this?

Here is an screenshot of the example:

[image: Example of Shaper Tool artifact]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: shaper tool or shape builder tool?

Comment: Use round corners or join them

Comment: GoofyMonkey - Shaper Tool - using the scribble gesture to cut out the corners.

Comment: joojaa - thank you, but neither of these do anything. That is, when I try to use round corners, there is no change. When I try to use the join tool on these corners, nothing happens either.

Comment: joojaa, you were right - I needed to join them but I needed to expand the shaper group first. Thank you very much and thanks goofymonkey too

Comment: Adobe has no quality control for design of new features in illustrator. They dont actually think of the implocations on the whole application ecosystem. As a result adobe seems to release 3 broken things for each thing worth keeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, expand the octagon object *(composed of 2 squares)*:

```
Object > Expand
```

Ungroup all the groups that have been created *(multiples ungroup or script ungroup all)*:

```
Object > Ungroup (multiples)
```

Join the segments into a single path:

```
Object > Path > Join
```

---

Another fast way to get an octagon *(or other polygons)*:

- draw a triangle with the shaper tool;
- select the triangle you just created;
- click the square tilted to the side and drag to increase the sides until an octagon is obtained.

[image: triangle]

Comment: @TommyDraughn You are welcome! If you liked it, do not forget to accept the answer :)